# flowplayer - display an image instead of the player

Tags: javascript, video, flowplayer

Good day to all. I have a movie that need 2 be displayed with flowplayer. The problem is that the first frame of the movie is white, background is white, everything is white. I want to use an image or colo or whatever instead of the first frame. This is the code I have:

```
   <a href="{$baseurl}/mm.flv" style="background: #000000; margin-bottom: 30px; height: 113px; display: block; position: relative;" id="player102" style="padding-bottom: 10px"></a>
<script> 
    flowplayer("player102", "/js/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.5.swf", {ldelim}
         plugins: {ldelim}
            controls: null
        {rdelim},

         clip:  {ldelim}
            autoPlay: false,
            autoBuffering: true
        {rdelim}
    {rdelim});
</script>
```

Is smarty template,

{rdelim} = }

{ldelim} = {.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this

```
<param name="flashvars"
    value='config={"playlist":["LINK TO IMAGE HERE",{"url":"LINK TO VIDEO HERE","autoPlay":false}]}' />
```

You could also do this

```
<!-- setup things like in the minimal setup  -->
<a href="http://pseudo01.hddn.com/vod/demo.flowplayervod/flowplayer-700.flv" id="player"
    style="display:block;width:425px;height:300px">

    <!-- specify a splash image inside the container -->
    <img src="/img/home/flow_eye.jpg" alt="Search engine friendly content" />

</a>
```

http://flowplayer.org/demos/installation/splash-image.html

Comment: I manage to do it with a kind of playlist... but your version looks acceptable too (although I didn't check it I think it works).